# Hiding a static class behind an interface - EventHandlers

Tags: c#, events, interface

I'm doing some maintenance on an existing project that has static service classes coming out the waazoo.

Basically I've had some success hiding them behind an interface + wrapper class that calls through directly to the existing static.

BUT

There are some of the existing static classes that have event handlers and wrapping these inside a property will not work since the EventHandler can only be on the left hand side of a += or -=.

The only way around this I can think of is to provide methods for adding and removing EventHandlers in the wrapper class which then accesses the static class event handler.

Is there a way to do it so the existing += and -= does not need to be changed?

eg, the existing use of the static classes is

```
SomeExistingStaticClass.SomeEventHandler += MyMethod;
```

refactored to

```
IStaticInterface myClass = new WrapperSomeExistingStaticClass();
myClass.SomeEventHandler += MyMethod;
```

and inside the wrapper I've tried to have SomeEventHandler as a property with a getter like this

```
public EventHandler SomeEventHandler
{
    get
    {
        return SomeExistingStaticClass.SomeEventHandler;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing, or is the best solution here to use an AddHandler and RemoveHandler method on the wrapper class?

Comment: You might be able to emulate the syntax by creating a custom collection of delegates that overrides the operators in question and notifies on property changed. I can't think of an easier way to preserve the functionality and syntax at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing a new event in your wrapper class, and then implement custom event accessors? in here you could reroute the events from the static service class, and keep your eventhandlers in sync. See [here (custom event accessors)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) for a simple example.

Comment: that would let me keep the existing event handling syntax and I suppose its not too much extra boilerplate code to add. Was hoping there was something I was missing but the MSDN doco seems pretty explicit, and the base class example seems to confirm that [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx)

Comment: @nrjohnstone: I think the only reason this is a problem in the first place is that you're trying to get around a static. Code issues tend to leak into other areas. As long as you're unable to fix the design, you'll have to do hacky workarounds that you hate. Events are quite simple, and do their job well. It doesn't sound like the problem is your fault, though. It's just something you'll have to deal with.

Comment: @Magus so true :-) Trying to make the best of a bad situation but I can't just go in and remove the static, hacky workaround here we go